# Sending parameters to a prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, prototype

Is it possible to send a parameter to a prototype to set new properties of an object?
for example:

```
function person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
this.firstName = first;
this.lastName = last;
this.age = age;
this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

person.prototype = function(color) {
    this.hair_color = color;
};
```

This may not have been implemented correctly, but my question is still the same. I am trying to make sure I understand prototypes so maybe I am missing a fundamental idea about them. It seems that everywhere I look prototypes are used to set defined variables as opposed to one that is input such as this

```
person.prototype = function() {
    this.hair_color = "brown";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototype allows you add new properties and correct way of doing that will be:

```
person.prototype.hair_color = "brown";
```

Comment: I think it is important to mention that now all person have brown hair.